# Are there other alternatives to "ekzemple"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

If you write a text it can get very repetative if you use the same word too much. Of course it depends on the word, but *ekzemple* is, in my opinion, pretty "heavy". What can I say instead? Can I replace it with a single word or are there alternatives that require rearranging of the sentence?

In Swedish we have *bland annat*, which I suppose is *among other things* in English. I rember seeing *interalie* somewhere. Is that used often? Do many esperantists undersand it?

I think one can use *kiel* in this sense as well. Am I right?

The three would look like this:

- Li havas multajn malkutimajn ŝatokupojn, ekzemple ĉasi per pafarko, ludi buŝharmonikon kaj lerni konstruitajn lingvojn.
- Li havas multajn malkutimajn ŝatokupojn, interalie ĉasi per pafarko, ludi buŝharmonikon kaj lerni konstruitajn lingvojn.
- Li havas multajn malkutimajn ŝatokupojn kiel ĉasi per pafarko, ludi buŝharmonikon kaj lerni konstruitajn lingvojn.

Comment: Seems to make sense

Answer (score 1):

I would have spelled *inter aliaj* as two words. You could also say *nome* - among others.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need a word there.

- *Mi havas multajn hobiojn: naĝi* [or *naĝadon*], *promeni, kudri, kaj tiel plu.*

It is possible to use *kiel*, but it feels a little incomplete without *ekzemple*.

Alternatives include *specife, precize, nome... ktp* or *interalie, inkluzive de*. In some contexts you could use *tipe* ("typically, representatively").

Comment: Do you mean I should use ktp at the end instead or that I should just leave it? I feel like a sentence without that extra word wouldn't show that there are more to the list than those written. Thank you for all the options anyways!